# How to do socket programming inside an aspx form?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sockets

I am willing to do some socket programing inside an aspx form. I know it is weird but I have to do this.
My problem is I could not use `System.Net.Socket` and always get

> The type or namespace name 'Socket' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Net' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

It is not in Project reference list.
Do I should add some dll to the project or something?

Comment: Did you try `System.Net.Sockets.Socket` though?

Comment: "I have to do this" are you sure about that? It's a mixture of higher and lower level concepts that are rarely encountered together. Are you sure you've got the *right* solution to the problem you're facing?

Comment: Yes I do. I know it seems crazy, but trust me, I have to do it.

Comment: I should mark this question as the most stupid question ever!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the class `System.Net.Sockets.Socket`.
It's part of the most basic `System` dll so no need to add references.

But I'm not sure what you'd want it for in WebForms.

Comment: How stupid am I! I just missed 's' in Sockets! second time when I used `System.Net.Sockets.Socket` it told me `'System.Net.Sockets.Socket' is a type not a namespace`